# "Find in page" vs "find on page"

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, formality, internet

I'd like to find some thoughts and opinions related to this question.
First of all, I noticed that there are two forms used in Web browsers' menus: MS Internet Explorer uses "Find on page" meanwhile Chrome uses "Find in page".

What is the difference between these forms and why can they both be used?

Normally, I'd say "find in the page" meaning "find in this text".

Comment: You're speaking of webpages?

Comment: Yes, this question is about web pages in web browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What constitutes "on" vs. what constitutes "in" is contextual and regional.  Bostonians wait "on line", while Chicagoans wait "in line".  George Carlin had a whole bit about "getting on the plane".  "Fuck you, I am getting *in* the plane!  Let the daredevils get *on*."

My intuition is that most native speakers would say "on" the page rather than "in", because a page is more like a platform than a container (whereas they would always "in the book").

Comment: Could you explain the "platform" meaning of a page.In my view a web page represents some content and there is nothing "on" it. This meaning is not so obvious to me, please give a clue)

Comment: @matreshkin -- I meant that literally: a "platform" in the sense that you can put something on it.

Comment: I see, but that's why I cannot understand this meaning - how we can "put" something on the "top of" a web page. It seems rather illogical.

Comment: Finally, the answer is the most popular, I suppose - "because people say so" :) Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @matreshkin -- well, language is always consensus.  Perhaps it would be easier to think of a chalkboard rather than a platform: you write "on" it.